# Java: how to allow only an annotated method call to be a function parameter?

Tags: java, annotations

Let's say I have a following class:

```
class Measurement {

    public final double temperature, pressure, humidity;
    private final String uuid;

    public Measurement() {
        // ...
    }

    @Uuid
    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }
}
```

Note that the `getUuid()` method is annotated with a custom `@Uuid` annotation. I also have a class that can represent an object of the `Measurement` class, or any other class that has a method annotated with `@Uuid`, in a following way:

```
public class ObjectRow extends Vector<String> {

    private final String uuid;

    public ObjectRow(@Uuid String uuid, String... data) {
        super();
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.addAll(Arrays.asList(data));
    }

    public String getObjectUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }
}
```

Now, is there a way to actually make this constructor only accept a `@Uuid` annotated method call as the `uuid` parameter, for example by throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` or by giving an IDE warning in a similar manner to the `@MagicConstant` annotation from `org.intellij.lang.annotations`? Example:

```
Measurement latest = productionHall.getLatestMeasurement();
table.add(new ObjectRow(latest.getUuid(),                       // OK
                        latest.temperature + "°C",
                        latest.pressure + "hPa",
                        latest.humidity + "%");
table.add(new ObjectRow("9be8238e-4098-d8a4-adcd-4755abdf95d0", // Exception or warning
                        latest.temperature + "°C",
                        latest.pressure + "hPa",
                        latest.humidity + "%");
table.add(new ObjectRow(UUID.randomUUID().toString(),           // Exception or warning
                        latest.temperature + "°C",
                        latest.pressure + "hPa",
                        latest.humidity + "%");
```

Comment: CheckerFramework can do that. Take a look here: https://checkerframework.org/manual/#subtyping-checker